# section numbering format

Tags: sectioning, formatting, numbering

I am trying to format a legal document so that it follows this format.

```
  Article 1.

1.01 First section

  bla bla bla

1.02 Second section

  bla bla bla

etcetera.
```

I tried using this to get things working the way I wanted:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}  %needed to make chapters continuous on page
%% Need with {etoolbox} package
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi}{}{}{}
\makeatother

% change % chapter to article and center it
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Article}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Alph{chapter}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\LARGE\bfseries\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0.125in}{\LARGE}

%Format section numbering
\def\thesection{\arabic{section}.}
\def\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.0\arabic{subsection}}
\def\thesubsubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}.\arabic{subsubsection}}

% Set section number depth to level 3
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

Now, the problem is how to get a leading zero in the section and then
have it increment correctly. Once I reach the 10 level, the section is
shown as: "1.010", which is wrong. It should read "1.10". I can
accomplish this in MS Word; however, I can find no way to do it in
LaTeX. Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 7):

The kernel macro `\two@digits` is what you're looking for. It produces the number given as its argument with a padding zero, if needed.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection.\two@digits{\value{subsection}}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection.\two@digits{\value{subsubsection}}}
\makeatother
```

Surrounding the code with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` is necessary when using kernel macros with `@` in their name.

The redefinition of `\thesubsubsection` seems in line with that of `\thesubsection`.

Thanks to Qrrbrbirlbel for having suggested `\value` instead of `\arabic`, which is indeed better because it stops expansion in search for digit, because `\two@digits` uses `\number`.

Comment: Is `\arabic` safe or should `\value` used instead?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel You're right; I forgot about `\number` and so `\value` is better.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel `\value` or `\two@digits{\@arabic\c@subsection}`