# How do I set up sections to be padded with leading 0s?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I am formatting a document for someone, and he wants each section number to be three digits long, starting with 000, and with padding zeros when needed.

[I found a similar question, and tried to adapt the example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/101712/section-numbering-format), but it gives me a

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\thesection ->\thesection 
                          .\three@digits {\value {section}}
l.11 \section{Synopsis}

If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
```

My MNWE is:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

 %Padding the leading zeros \makeatletter
 \renewcommand\thesection{\thesection.\three@digits{\value{section}}}
 \makeatother

 \begin{document} \setcounter{section}{-1} \tableofcontents
 \section{Synopsis} foo

 \section{Language} bar

 \section{Legal} baz

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You actually have a recursive definition for `\thesection`, since `\thesection` contains `\thesection`, which contained `\thesection`, which contains `\thesection`, ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There exists no `\three@digits` in the [kernel](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) by default. However, you can define it, and you also need to adjust the ToC-related number spacing for sections:

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

%Padding the leading zeros
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}{1.5em}{2em}{}{}% Adjust section ToC number width
%\def\two@digits#1{\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\number#1}% http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx
\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1>99\else\ifnum#1>9 0\else00\fi\fi\number#1}
\renewcommand\thesection{\three@digits{\value{section}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document} 
\setcounter{section}{-1}
\tableofcontents
\section{Synopsis} foo

\section{Language} bar

\section{Legal} baz

\end{document}
```

The ToC-related spacing is adjusted using an [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) patch. You may want to adjust the `\subsection` spacing as well which is defined as

```
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
```

by default (from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls)). Here `1.5em` is the indent and `2.3em` is the space for the numbers. So you might go with

```
\renewcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{2em}{3em}}
```

say.

---

For more on padding counters with zeroes, see [How to output a counter with leading zeros?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30930/5764)

Comment: I'd already adjusted the spacing with `tocloft`, I just removed that from my example to make it minimal. It seems to be nice and compatible, thank you.